# How to install azure-cli package from an older Ubuntu release?

Tags: package-management, upgrade, repository, 19.10

I upgraded my Ubuntu to 19.10 Eoan Ermine and I want to install the azure-cli package, but it is currently only available on 19.04.

As in the docs, I'm executing the following command to add the repository:

```
AZ_REPO=$(lsb_release -cs)
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ $AZ_REPO main" | 
    sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azure-cli.list
```

but then I try to `apt-get install azure-cli` I receive this:

`The repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli eoan Release' does not have a Release file.`

Is it possible to use the disco repository to install this package via apt?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It is possible but you may face a dependency issue, in rare cases binary incompatible libraries too. If you can't get an answer here from anyone that tried it, Use a virtual-box and test  if you would like. At least you keep your production system clean, if it fails. If it works, please share the answer.

Comment: You've already said it was available for 'disco', so why did you add the 'eoan' (your release via $AZ_REPO) repository in your listed commands rather than the 'disco' where it is available.  Before I'd add it to my 19.10 system I'd do some homework/testing to ensure security/stability - but your commands doesn't fit what you tried to do.

Comment: @guiverc I followed the manual install instructions given in the docs, at https://docs.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-apt?view=azure-cli-latest .

Comment: My point was to not just blindly cut/paste, but look at what you pasted in command and you'll quickly note the $AZ_REPO gets populated with your release (it'll get *focal* for my box), where this should be replaced by ....   *There are risks in doing that, which I suspect you're not up for accessing... but is a quick dirty way to get what you wanted*

Comment: You are right, I am a newbie in Ubuntu and I don't really know what is this lsb_release variable that seems to be assigned to AZ_REPO... and I don't know if I can replace it with anything else that points to the Disco repository. And as you say, that might be a dirty workaround for what I want, but currently I do not have much of a choice.

Comment: @FelipeWagner you should ask Microsoft for supporting 19.10 through their official support channel.

Comment: @N0rbert yes, I did it already, this "feature" is on their milestone that will be on mid december. Currently my alternative is using a docker container with an Ubuntu 18.04 image, but that's not related to my question, so I don't know if it would be an answer.

Comment: @FelipeWagner, I changed the title, now that could be an answer :). Ping me when you submit, so I vote

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, azure-cli is available as a snapd package (https://snapcraft.io/install/azure-cli/ubuntu).

So, maybe you can try: `sudo snap install azure-cli --candidate`

(Sorry, I can't test it on my machine)

Comment: I did it in the first time, but apparently the snap package is so outdated that you can't even follow the current docs with it, and it's not supporting the latest version of docker.

Comment: Too bad ... sorry for that